# Target Org Community user unable to access Protected custom setting in Managed package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, customer-community, customsetting, permission-sets

We have created a custom lightning component for one of our client who are utilizing our Managed package. We are calling a managed package global apex class from this custom lightning component where the logic stands. There is a Protected Custom setting where we are storing UserName password for callouts(We have managed package VF page to update the login creds). We are accessing this protected custom setting in Apex class which is used in custom lightning component in client Org and doing a REST callout on click of a button.

Community users who are accessing this Lightning component are unable to access the Protected custom setting to perform REST API. Internal users have No issues whatsoever. I checked the Permission sets and we do have *"View All Custom Settings"*, *"Allow Api"* and other permissions required and same permission sets are assigned to Internal users as well. If the protected custom setting SOQL is null, There is a response message to lightning component That's how I found that the Community users are not accessing the custom setting at all.

What am I missing? Why Community user unable to access the Protected Custom setting in target org? Please advise. Thanks.